# css nth-child or nth-of-type

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

I would like to avoid using a function or loop in a custom Wordpress template to display a different background colour for a certain element.  My issue is the containers that need to be changed and their parent container.

Every 1st, 4th, 7th, etc profile class needs to have a background colour of blue. Every 2nd, 5th, 8th, etc profile class needs to have a background colour of red.  Every 3rd, 6th, 9th, etc needs to have a background colour of green.

I've tried using different combinations of the .profile:nth-child and .profile:nth-of-type but only having 2 instances of the class within the staff parent class resets the background colour.

At the moment I get something like this:

```
<div class="staff">
    <div class="profile">
    (blue)
    </div>
    <div class="profile">
    (red)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="staff">
    <div class="profile">
    (blue)
    </div>
    <div class="profile">
    (red)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="staff">
    <div class="profile">
    (blue)
    </div>
    <div class="profile">
    (red)
    </div>
</div>
....
```

when what I want to see is:

```
<div class="staff">
    <div class="profile">
    (blue)
    </div>
    <div class="profile">
    (red)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="staff">
    <div class="profile">
    (green)
    </div>
    <div class="profile">
    (blue)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="staff">
    <div class="profile">
    (red)
    </div>
    <div class="profile">
    (green)
    </div>
</div>
....
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little complicated, but assuming every `.staff` element will only contain at most 2 `.profile` elements, [it can be done](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/T2y2W) — even once the `.staff` groups begin repeating:

```
.staff:nth-child(3n+1) .profile:nth-child(1),
.staff:nth-child(3n+2) .profile:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: blue;
}

.staff:nth-child(3n+1) .profile:nth-child(2),
.staff:nth-child(3n+3) .profile:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
}

.staff:nth-child(3n+2) .profile:nth-child(1),
.staff:nth-child(3n+3) .profile:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Note that `:nth-of-type()` won't make a difference assuming your `.staff` elements are the only `div` elements in their parent, since `:nth-of-type()` only looks at the tag name, and all your `.profile` elements are also `div`s anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  That worked perfectly.  However, my client came back and wanted to throw a spanner into the works by adding another div in, effectively making the code now look like this - http://jsfiddle.net/TP3R2/ - which makes every second profile block have the desired background colour.  I tried editing your jsfiddle but could not get it to work.

Comment: @ToddyBoy: Ah, I was worried for a moment there but it isn't as complicated as it seems. It looks like every `.profile` is just being preceded by a `.photo` now. In that case, just change every `.profile:nth-child(2)` to `.profile:nth-child(4)` and every `.profile:nth-child(1)` to `.profile:nth-child(1)`. Here's another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/T2y2W/1 `:nth-of-type()` still won't make a difference as they are all `div`s.

Comment: Legend!  Worked a charm!